# how could I modify bootstrap navbar with justify content between?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm trying to set up a navbar in bootstrap 4 where the brand, the nav items, and contact buttons are evenly spaced across the entire container, however, I'm having a hard time getting it like this, I tried justify-content-between but not working. Though it does respond to justify-content-center it doesn't render how I want it. Any idea Where I'm going wrong?

```
 <div class="container">

       
        <div class="row justify-content-between">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="navbar-brand text-success" href="#">
                    KT Mode
                    </a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                            data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                            aria-expanded="false"
                            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
        
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
                        id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link"
                                href="#">
                                My Work
                                <span class="sr-only">
                                    (current)
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link"
                                href="#">
                                About
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link"
                                href="#">
                                Events
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link"
                                href="#">
                                Learn
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="align-content-end">
                            <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                            <i class="bi bi-youtube"></i>
                            <!--
                            <span class="material-icons">info</span>s
                            <span class="material-icons">info</span>
                            -->
                             <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm">Contact</button>
                             
        
                             <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
                             aria-hidden="true">
                             <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                               <div class="modal-content">
                                 <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                   <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Write to us</h4>
                                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                   </button>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                                   <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                     <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                                     <input type="text" id="form34" class="form-control validate">
                                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form34">Your name</label>
                                   </div>
                           
                                   <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                     <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                                     <input type="email" id="form29" class="form-control validate">
                                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form29">Your email</label>
                                   </div>
                           
                                   <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                     <i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
                                     <input type="text" id="form32" class="form-control validate">
                                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form32">Subject</label>
                                   </div>
                           
                                   <div class="md-form">
                                     <i class="fas fa-pencil prefix grey-text"></i>
                                     <textarea type="text" id="form8" class="md-textarea form-control" rows="4"></textarea>
                                     <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form8">Your message</label>
                                   </div>
                           
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                   <button class="btn btn-unique">Send <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                                 </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                           </div>
                           
                           <div class="text-center">
                             <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContactForm"></a>
                           </div>
        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            
        </div>
    
        
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">


    <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light justify-content-between">
            <div class="container justify-content-between">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-success" href="#">
                    KT Mode
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-around" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                My Work
                                <span class="sr-only">
                                    (current)
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                Events
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                Learn
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="align-content-end">
                        <i class="bi bi-instagram"></i>
                        <i class="bi bi-youtube"></i>
                        <!--
                        <span class="material-icons">info</span>s
                        <span class="material-icons">info</span>
                        -->



                        <div class="modal fade" id="modalContactForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                            aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Write to us</h4>
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                                        <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                            <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <input type="text" id="form34" class="form-control validate">
                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form34">Your
                                                name</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                            <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <input type="email" id="form29" class="form-control validate">
                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form29">Your
                                                email</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="md-form mb-5">
                                            <i class="fas fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <input type="text" id="form32" class="form-control validate">
                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right"
                                                for="form32">Subject</label>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <i class="fas fa-pencil prefix grey-text"></i>
                                            <textarea type="text" id="form8" class="md-textarea form-control"
                                                rows="4"></textarea>
                                            <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form8">Your
                                                message</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                                        <button class="btn btn-unique">Send <i
                                                class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#modalContactForm"></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modalContactForm">Contact</button>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </div>
</div>
```

put the button outside of the navbar-collapse and add class to the container justify-content-between, also add class to the navbar-collapse that justify-content-around